# ERROR after I changed to python 2.7from python3 ( anaconda3 and eclipse )

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7

use following cmd:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
```

inorder to change python3 to python 2.7

then i ran the code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
import csv
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO

# Read in the csv file and put features into list of dict and list of      class label
allElectronicsData = open(r'D:\mycodes\test01\AllElectronics.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(allElectronicsData)
headers = reader.next()
```

error:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\huanjing\eclipse-java-neon-R-win32-    x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.7.0.201704111357\pysrc\_pydev_runfi    les\pydev_runfiles.py", line 468, in __get_module_from_str
mod = __import__(modname)
File "D:\mycodes\test01\tree.py", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction
ERROR: Module: tree could not be imported (file:         D:/mycodes/test01/tree.py).
done.

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

### OK

It looks like after I change the python version ，I need to install all the python package in conda again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Python 2.7 and Python 3 will use different packages. Run the following commands in you conda environment:

```
$ conda install numpy
$ conda install scipy
$ conda install scikit-learn
```

Comment: no problem, I see you're new to SO. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.